# 5V Short circuit protection circuit that lights an LED in the event of a dead short

Tags: circuit-protection

I'm looking to implement a dead short protection circuit for a PCB so that if a dead short occurs in the circuit a LED lights up and the circuit is protected and no current flows. THe LED is to stay lit until the short goes away.

While i am new to electronics i assume this is a common circuit but i have been unable to find a simple example using resistors and transistors.

Edit: here is an attempt at what i mean, but not sure if this is workable or not.

[image: Circuit attempt]

Comment: "if a dead short occurs in the circuit" This is very vague, what's "the circuit"? You can only do something like that in a specific part of it. The alternative would be a fuse on the supply.

Comment: How many ohms is a dead short? How much current flows in that situation? Please note resistance is not zero and the short circuit current is not infinite. And it can't be done simply with resistors and diodes.

Comment: Thankyou for the replies, and forgive my vagueness as I am learning.

I was thinking this would sit next to the incoming solder pads of 5V and GND. And would cut the 5V rail after this protection circuit in the event the 5V rail was ever connected directly to ground by mistake and light an LED to let me know i've done something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the stack.  Here you'll find people with lots of electrical design experience, willing to help.  However, you'll need to make an effort to both clearly articulate your question, and demonstrate you've done at least some research yourself.  You've already got good comments asking you to provide more details including trip current, and you should edit your question to provide this extra information (rather than adding comments).

Comment: You are unlikely to find a solution involving just diodes and resistors, because you almost certainly need a very non-linear response.  By that I mean little if any voltage drop until you hit your trip current, then you want your protection to effectively go open circuit.

Comment: @colintd thankyou for your patience, i have edited the question and spent a couple of hours attempting a version of a circuit.

Comment: Without any constraints specified, the simplest implementation of what you seem to describe, would simply be a PTC thermistor / polymer fuse.  Put an LED+resistor across it to indicate faulting. Indeed even a plain resistor instead of the fuse might do what you ask.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add _foldback current limiting_ to an existing power supply. Googling for "foldback" may be helpful.

Comment: Why not get a power supply with current limiting built in?

Answer (score 2):

If short circuit protection is a must, it is well worth selecting a 5V regulator which includes this function.  For instance this [cheap 3-pin device](https://docs.rs-online.com/7b04/A700000006631898.pdf) is a drop in replacement for 3-pin linear devices, but has much higher efficiency, and with hard limit output current.

If you added a LED+resistor from Vin to Vout you'd also get your short indicator function.